# for raspberry pi can i use node js to have it be controlled by a website

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Will I be able to use the raspberry pi with node.js to control something connected to the pi with a website with wifi. And also will it be the same as php or will it have limitations

Comment: "use the raspberry pi" is very vague.  "control something connected to the pi" is very vague.  "will it have limitations" is very vague.  You should offer up more details and ask a more specific question.  Otherwise the answer is just going to be an equally vague "yes, anything is possible".

Comment: @Wyck well i don't have anything now it on its way trying to get everything before it arrives

Comment: Did you try searching the web for information about using node.js on raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, definitely !

Without knowing anything specific about what you are trying to achieve, I would say yes, no problem. I do it all the time. For example a simple NodeJs WebServer that serves a webpage, including a WebSocket Server to receive real-time commands or via REST API. Almost anything is possible.